# jQuery animation to opacity is not appeared again after fade out

Tags: jquery, animation, opacity, fade

I am developing an web application. I am using jQuery for front end. Frankly, I am not good at front end. Now I have a problem with animating an element on button click event. What I animating opacity.

But the problem animation is not fired when the button is fired second time. What I am doing is shopping cart add button. When the page is loaded, quantity is hidden. When user click add button, quantity will be shown with new count. Then fade out slowly. But the problem is it does not appear again after it fades out for first time.

This is my add to cart button click event

```
$('.instant-add-to-cart-btn').on('click', function (e) {

        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var url = $('.add-to-cart-url').val();
        var $quan = $('#instant-quantity-span-' + id);
        $quan.css({ "opacity": 1 })
        $.post(url, { itemId: id, belonging: 0, quantity: 1 }, function (data) {
            var count = parseInt($quan.text()) + 1;
            $quan.text(count);
            $quan.animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, 1000)
        });

    });
```

This is the css of the quantity span

```
span[id^=instant-quantity-span]{
    font-size:25px;
    margin-right:5px;
    vertical-align:top;
    display:inline-block;
    opacity:0;
}
```

Initially, it is not displayed. It display each time a button a click and then slowly. But as I mentioned, it never appears again after fade out even I click several times.

Comment: Check this sample...it works on chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/epdgkuny/

Comment: Not working properly. It is obvious when I click frequently very fast. What I want is if user click buttton again before the first one fade out, it will set the opacity again.

Comment: It is pretty tricky, because you can not control the time an ajax call could take, but, take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/epdgkuny/1/

Comment: Yeah. That is ok. I can use it. Thanks.

Comment: No problem @Wai Yan Hein...I am glad to help :)

Comment: I found out that adding this $quan.removeAttr('style'); before this $quan.css({ "display": "inline-block" }).show() works perfectly. Thanks a lot.